# Find an example to show that two statements are not equal

Tags: logic

Find an example to show that $(\exists x)(A(x)\land B(x))\neq (\exists x)A(x)\land (\exists x)B(x)$.

Does this mean that on the RHS some $x$ for which $A(x)$ is true is not the same as some other $x$ for which $B(x)$ is true?

For example:

$A(x)$: $x$ is even

$B(x)$ $x$ is greater than $2$

Then for $(\exists x)(A(x)\land B(x))$ we have $(\exists x)(2|x \land x>2)$

That's true if we take for example $x=4$.

For $(\exists x)A(x)\land (\exists x)B(x)$ we get $(\exists x)(2|x)\land (\exists x)(x>2)$.

For $(\exists x)(2|x)$ we can take $x=2$, and for $(\exists x)(x>2)$ we can take $x=4$. So those two $x$'s can be different, is that the point here?

Comment: Maybe you can say that $A(x) : x$ is even and $B(x): x$ is odd

Answer (score 4):

Your example does not work

A counterexample could be

- $A(x)$: $x$ is even
- $B(x)$: $x$ is odd

Of course the proof is up to you.

Note that the first statement is saying:

> there exists some $x$ such that both statements hold *simultaneously* for the same $x$,

whereas the second statement is saying:

> there exists some $x$ such that statement $A$ holds (i.e. $A$ is not always false) and there exists some $y$ such that $B$ holds.

Where I chose the letter $y$ and not $x$ to show that the statements are to be though of independently, and not simultaneously as in the previous case.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence, which is the key to avoiding confusion.

Comment: @boon heT But how can there exist $x$ for which both $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are true in your example?

Comment: That's exactly the point you have to show in order for the two not to be equivant @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely. Thank you Ethan!